# Jquery parents() are not working properly

Tags: jquery

Use this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#origin").live("click",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#rest").toggle(200);
            });
            $("body").click(function(e){
                if($(this).parents("#rest").length<=0)
                {
                    $("#rest").hide(200);
                }
            });
        });
```

But when I click in inside the div id="rest" then the rest div hide. what the coding problem is?

Comment: What do you expect? I see no problems here unless you will tell us what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if($(this).parents("#rest").length<=0)
```

To:

```
if($("#rest").is(":visible"))
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error so please change this:

```
if($(this).parents("#rest").length<=0)
```

to:

```
if($(this).parent("#rest").length<=0)
```

I think you may be want to do this:

```
if($(this).parent().length<=0)
```